# how to use a variable value in my email template that fetch from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

My Email Format like

```
$confirmationcode = rand(10, 1000);
$unumber = uniqid();
$message= '<html><head></head><body>
          <div style="height:600px; width:100%; "> 
            <h3>'.$fetch_tration.'<br></div></body> </html>';

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'example@example.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '************';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('example@example.com', 'Admin Team');
        $this->email->to(example@example.com);
        $this->email->subject('Confirm  Registration');
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
        $this->email->send();
```

in email code $fetch_tration is email template that look like

> Please CONFIRM your registration with www.doamin.Com

where Confirm text has a link like 
    http://example.com/mycon/emailconfirmation/'.$confirmationcode.'/'.$unumber.'

I want To replace $confirmationcode and $unumber with value which assign at mail time.
when someone register than email send successfully but the variable $confirmationcode and $unumber not assign in the link. when user click on confirm link thank get an error like

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Please help 
Thank In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are use CodeIgniter as your framework then u can directly allowed permitted character from config file.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=';
```

Can you please upload full link so, it's easy to understand exact issue.

```
http://example.com/mycon/emailconfirmation/'.$confirmationcode.'/'.$unumber.'
```

If you get upper link as a on click button, then it's totally wrong and you have to use "str_replace" function for replace url from template.

EXA:

```
$emaildata['message'] = file_get_contents(ASSETS_URL.'email_templates/filename');
$emaildata['message'] = str_replace('ReplacetagName', $YourVariable, $emaildata['message']);
```

Comment: yeah for your email template you can replace variable with template hatml tag value.

$emaildata['message'] = file_get_contents(ASSETS_URL.'email_templates/filename');
$emaildata['message'] = str_replace('ReplacetagName', $YourVariable, $emaildata['message']);